# Create Stock Quantity Variable in Firestore with Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I want to create a collection in Firestore through flutter where I can store a quantity variable which gets updated when I stock in and stock out items through my flutter app. However I can't seem to understand how to create that. How should I store that and how should I update the quantity field on stocking in and out items?

Answer (score 1):

A collection is automatically created when its first document is created.

So if you need to manage only one stock you can create (initiate) a unique document in e.g. a `stock` collection and assign the initial stock. This initialization can very well be done through the Firestore console,

Then, to adapt the stock quantity, it depends on your global functional requirement:

1. If you just want to increment/decrement the stock quantity without impacting any other document in Firestore you can use the [`FieldValue.increment()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value) method (use a negative value to decrement).
2. If your operation must be transactional and involves some other Firestore document (e.g. you modify a bank account, or a e-commerce basket, or another stock in parallel to this stock operation) you should use a [Transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#dart).

---

You may also consider if you really want to allow this operation from your Flutter app and not from a back-end (e.g. Cloud Functions). To allow end users to do this from an app you'll have to open the write access to one or more collections and a malicious user could change the stock value in an undesired way if you cannot implement a security rule that prevents that.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to figure something out using transactions.